# Not able to generate correct build.xml for android test project

Tags: android

I have created a main android project using "android" utility. e.g.

android create project --target 1 --name MyApp --path C:\testandroid\myui --activity LaunchActivity --package com.myui.activity

build.xml got generated fine (has ant targets like debug, release etc)

I generated a test android project (which depends on main project). I used "android" utility to do that. e.g.

android create test-project --path C:\testandroid\myuitest --main ..\myui --name MfAppTest

build.xml got generated but incorrect (does not have targets like run-tests). It has same targets as main project.

Can someone help as where is the problem?
Thx.
Ashley

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old already, but anyway here I go: you will see the same targets by running

ant -p

on both the app and the test project. Don't worry about that.

Try to do the following from the test project's root:

ant clean instrument install test

considering you have one and only one device connected (physical or emulator).